# UITableViewCell not displaying contents from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, segue

I am working on Fitness(workout) scheduler app with SWRevealView Controller, which offers side bar menu feature.

I have tried to link one cell from the side bar menu to another Tableview controller, where I have set segue between them.

The segue is fine, but it does not display the text data that I have in the mutable array.

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;
@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *plans;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *categories;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
//    [UITableView setDelegate:self];
//    [UITableView setDataSource:self];

    self.plans = @[@{@"name" : @"Week 1-3", @"category" : @"Buff Dudes Workout"}, @{@"name" : @"Week 4-6", @"category" : @"Buff Dudes Workout"}, @{@"name" : @"Week 7-9", @"category" : @"Buff Dudes Workout"}, @{@"name" : @"Week 10-12", @"category" : @"Buff Dudes Workout"}].mutableCopy;
    self.categories = @[@"Buff Dudes Workout"];


    self.title = @"Workout Programs";

    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
        [self.sidebarButton setTarget: self.revealViewController];
        [self.sidebarButton setAction: @selector( revealToggle: )];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - DataSource helper methods

- (NSArray *) itemsInCategory:(NSString *)targetCategory {
    NSPredicate *matchingPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == %@", targetCategory];
    NSArray *categoryItems = [self.plans filteredArrayUsingPredicate:matchingPredicate];

    return categoryItems;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInCategory:(NSString *)targetCategory {
    return [self itemsInCategory:targetCategory].count;
}

- (NSDictionary *)itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *category = self.categories[indexPath.section];
    NSArray *categoryItems = [self itemsInCategory:category];
    NSDictionary *item = categoryItems[indexPath.row];

    return item;
}

- (NSInteger)itemIndexForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *item = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger index = [self.plans indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:item];

    return index;
}

//- (void)removeitemsAtindexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//    NSInteger index = [self itemIndexForIndexPath:indexPath];
//    [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:index];


#pragma mark - table view datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return self.categories.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self numberOfItemsInCategory:self.categories[section]];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"workoutplanrow";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *plans = [self itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = plans[@"name"];



    return cell;

}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.categories[section];
}

@end
```

I think there is something wrong in my `ellForRowAtIndexPath method`.

Comment: Check if your nsmutable is correctly allocated before use it

Comment: why are `setDelegate` and `setDataSource` commented out?

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"cell.textLabel.text %@", cell.textLabel.text);` after setting text `cell.textLabel.text = plans[@"name"];`. Does it actually have value? Or is it null?

Comment: @ozgur maybe he set it in the storyboard.

Comment: Make sure your tableView dataSource and delegate in IB are pointed to MainViewController. Also, add a reference to your tableView and call reloadData() after setting plans and categories.

Comment: @thattyson I have connected the reference outlets "dataSource" and "delegate" to MainViewController, and now it gives me the "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" Error. I have searched about this error, and i think i have the correct "numberOfRowsInSection " method in the MainViewController.m

Comment: @thattyson Im stuck at this point, could you help?

Comment: @SFF I have tried NSLog to see if the array has value in it, but i don't see any log on the Xcode, even in the console area...

Comment: @DonaldSeo Make sure your dragged to files owner, not the view. Seems you may have attached the delegate and dataSource to the View in IB instead of files owner.

Comment: @thattyson Thank you so much !! As you said, i connected to view, instead of files owner. I would like to select your answer but its on comment.. maybe you could rewrite the comment on answer so that i can select it as a good answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your tableView dataSource and delegate in IB are connected to files owner (MainViewController).
2. Add a reference to your tableView and call `tableView.reloadData()` after setting plans and categories.